# How to find the first index in a string which is not a specific char

Tags: node.js, string

I have a phone number which i want to strip it's leading zeros.
What is the best way to find the first digit which is not 0? (input is a string)

Answer (score -1):

you can simply create a for-loop that runs from 0 - ( insert string.length() or whatever it is, I'm not a node.js programmer) and check using an if-expression if the character at the index is a zero, then simply write the index out if the character is not a zero.